# Sending user from Android app to a React native app using deep link

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, deep-linking

I have an issue regarding processing of a deep link. I am looking for a way for user to click a link inside an Android app for it to open new instance of a another react native app.

I have a deep link leading to the react apps correct view. Currently this is handled through intent class and it opens inside of the android app as a view. However this is not wanted behavior and I am trying to find out if it's possible to do otherwise.

`context.startActivity( Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Constants.PROFILE_LINK ) )`